# How to change this JS so that it returns a different string based on the Locale of the browser?

Tags: javascript

Please forgive me for the naivete of this question, I am trying to grab some JavaScript for the first time.

I have this JavaScript file that returns a string:

```
var strings = strings || {};

(function() {
strings.get = function(key) {
    var locale = "english";  //To be switched based on device locale when localisation occurs...

    return localeMap[locale][key];
};

strings.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    var str = strings.get(args[0]);
    return str.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, num) {
        return typeof args[+num + 1] != 'undefined' ? args[+num + 1] : match;
    });
};

var englishStrings = {
    "exercise.requires.max.force" : "You need to record your maximum strength before you can perform exercises. Would you like to record it now?",

    "calibration.start.alert" : "Ensure the PeriCoach device is connected and in position. During calibration, follow the on screen instructions, contracting your muscles as hard as you can when it says 'Squeeze' and relaxing completely when it says 'Relax'. You will be required to repeat this four times.",
    "calibration.starting" : "Starting...",

};

var localeMap = {
    english: englishStrings
};
})();
```

I want to change it so that it returns a string based on the locale of the browser,

I have done something like follows, but I do not know how to change this so that it returns the correct string,

obviously

```
var localeMap = {
    en-US: englishStrings
    it: italianStrings
};
```

Is wrong...
please what would be the correct form?

```
var strings = strings || {};

(function() {
strings.get = function(key) {
    var locale = "english";  //To be switched based on device locale when localisation occurs...
    var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
    return localeMap[language][key];
};

strings.format = function() {
    var args = arguments;
    var str = strings.get(args[0]);
    return str.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, num) {
        return typeof args[+num + 1] != 'undefined' ? args[+num + 1] : match;
    });
};

var englishStrings = {
    "testo" : "Inglese",
    "exercise.requires.max.force" : "You need to record your maximum strength before you can perform exercises. Would you like to record it now?",

    "calibration.start.alert" : "Ensure the PeriCoach device is connected and in position. During calibration, follow the on screen instructions, contracting your muscles as hard as you can when it says 'Squeeze' and relaxing completely when it says 'Relax'. You will be required to repeat this four times.",
    "calibration.starting" : "Starting...",

};

 var italianStrings = {
     "testo" : "Italiano",

    "exercise.requires.max.force" : "Italiano",
    "calibration.start.alert" : "Italiano",
    "calibration.starting" : "Italiano",
        };
var localeMap = {
    en-US: englishStrings
    it: italianStrings
};
})();
```

Comment: question length is inversely proportional to the number of answers ;)

Comment: @GovindSinghNagarkoti that is sure :-)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're after. But the way you defined your object `localeMap` was incorrect.

```
var localeMap = {
    "en-US": englishStrings, //note the comma and quotes
    "it": italianStrings //quotes aren't necessary here
};
```

`localeMap.it || localeMap["it"]` and `localeMap["en-US"]` will return the objects with the strings in it.

**edit:**

The easiest way to set a default value would be to set `var loc = "en-US";` and overwrite it when another locale is detected. Then retrieve the strings like so: `localeMap[loc];`

Comment: thanks Luud, that worked!! Please how do I add a "default value" in case localeMap is neither localeMap["it"] nor localeMap["en-US"] ? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should declare the language of the page in the `html` tag as follows:

```
<html lang="en">
```

Why? http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1

Assuming that you set the lang attribute, then you can easy read it with JS/JQ:

With Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('lang')
```

With jQuery:

```
$('html').attr('lang')
```